# Monoid Instance form HList Record not working

Tags: haskell, overlap, monoids, hlist

I'm trying to define a `Monoid` instance for `HList Record` but I got a overlapping instance error message.
My attempt (the code looks complicated, but it's basically what would be the tuple instance)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Monoid
import Data.HList.FakePrelude
import Data.HList.Record
import Data.HList.Labelable

instance (Monoid v1, Monoid v2) => 
         Monoid (Record '[Tagged (t1::Symbol) v1, Tagged (t2::Symbol) v2]) where
    mempty = (Label :: Label (t1::Symbol)) .=. mempty
          .*. (Label :: Label (t2::Symbol)) .=. mempty .*. emptyRecord
    mappend a b = (Label :: Label (t1::Symbol)) 
               .=. (a .!. (Label :: Label (t1::Symbol)))
               `mappend` (b .!. (Label :: Label (t1::Symbol)))
               .*.(Label :: Label (t2::Symbol)) 
               .=. (a .!. (Label :: Label (t2::Symbol))) 
               `mappend` (b .!. (Label :: Label (t2::Symbol)))
               .*. emptyRecord
```

Error message:

```
Database/Harehouse/Utils.hs:185:59:
Overlapping instances for HEq Symbol l0 t1 b
  arising from a use of `.!.'
Matching instances:
  instance [overlap ok] 'False ~ b => HEq k x y b
    -- Defined in `Data.HList.TypeEqO'
  instance [overlap ok] HEq k x x 'True
    -- Defined in `Data.HList.TypeEqO'
(The choice depends on the instantiation of `t1, b, l0'
 To pick the first instance above, use -XIncoherentInstances
 when compiling the other instance declarations)
In the first argument of `mappend', namely
  `(a .!. (Label :: Label (t1 :: Symbol)))'
In the second argument of `(.=.)', namely
  `(a .!. (Label :: Label (t1 :: Symbol)))
   `mappend` (b .!. (Label :: Label (t1 :: Symbol)))'
In the first argument of `(.*.)', namely
  `(Label :: Label (t1 :: Symbol))
   .=.
     (a .!. (Label :: Label (t1 :: Symbol)))
     `mappend` (b .!. (Label :: Label (t1 :: Symbol)))'
```

What does that mean ? How can I solve this problem ? (I'm using GHC 7.6.3)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. GHC 7.8.2, HList-0.3.4.1

Comment: You need `ScopedTypeVariables` to get the t1 in the definition of mappend to match the one in the one above.

Comment: @aavogt: Of course!  I thought class declaration scoped variable, but apparently it doesn't for the instance declaration. Anyway, that works, you could create an answer that I can accept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ScopedTypeVariables` to get the t1 in the definition of mappend to match the one in the instance head above.

Also, the next HList release will have a Monoid instance which works like yours, except it isn't restricted to records with length 2. http://code.haskell.org/HList/Data/HList/HList.hs is the implementation (the instance for `Record` is written with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`)

Comment: I have a bit of code which generates the instances for all the length from 1 to 20 (or more if needed), but for the sake of the question I only provied the 2 length example ;-)  However, I'm looking forward to the next release. If you prefer a generated version to something needing a GHC extension I'm happy to provide you with the generator.